# Creating a line graph for multiple variables

Tags: r, linegraph

I am just wondering if someone can help.
I am working in R markdown and got the following set of data and same set every year for 5 years in the form of other sets of columns besides this set. KOOS_SYMP_1YR….etc.

KOOS_SYMP_6M    KOOS_PAIN_6M    KOOS_ADL_6M KOOS_SPORT_6M   KOOS_QOL_6M KOOS_WOMAC_6M   KOOS_TOTAL_6M   KOOS_SYMP_1Yr
67.86   80.56   100.00  65.00   68.75   3.00    83.33
64.30   63.90   75.00   30.00   18.80   27.00   60.10

46.43   80.56   79.41   50.00   50.00   19.00   67.86
68.00   78.00   76.00   50.00   56.00       70.20
50.00   50.00   60.00   10.00   19.00       46.40
32.14   47.22   60.29   20.00   31.25   41.00   45.24
82.14   86.11   77.94   60.00   50.00       75.60

There is over 600 observation in each column. Then the same data at 6 ms then at 1 years , 2 years, 3 years, 4 years and 5 years.

I want to plot them on a graph but not sure which is the ideal one to show the progression of each score over the year. E.g. KOOS_SYMP how is it progressing from 6 months until the 5 years mark.

I was thinking of plotting them on a line graph where the x axis is the time in years or 6 months. Then each score is represented by a line color. So, KOOS_SYMP red line, KOOS_ pain green line….etc. and the Y axis are the values of the scores?

But , I do not know how to plot that. Any idea or any other graph suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplot`. Here a basic one:

```
matplot(dat, type='l')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(67.86, 64.3, 46.43, 68, 50, 32.14, 82.14
), V2 = c(80.56, 63.9, 80.56, 78, 50, 47.22, 86.11), V3 = c(100, 
75, 79.41, 76, 60, 60.29, 77.94), V4 = c(65, 30, 50, 50, 10, 
20, 60), V5 = c(68.75, 18.8, 50, 56, 19, 31.25, 50), V6 = c(3, 
27, 19, NA, NA, 41, NA), V7 = c(83.33, 60.1, 67.86, 70.2, 46.4, 
45.24, 75.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: But this will plot each column as a line. In my case V1 to V5 are the variables at 6 months. Then V6 to V10 are the same variables at 1 year. Then V11 to V15 are the same variables at 2 years. I want to have the values of V1, V6 , V11 plotted as one line. X axis show time and Y axis show vlaues. So one line represents how a variable values changes over time